# Stop user from using 'X' button of browser

Tags: javascript, php, browser

I have a quiz appearing website where a user can appear for quiz. It has a feature of time out and auto submitting of quiz if time exceeds 30 minutes. Now the user who attempts the quiz is trying to stop the page processing when time-out occurs and stops the page loading by clicking the `X` button in browser. How can this be prevented. I have seen results for disabling `refresh` button and all but this is not my case. The user is stopping the page load when auto submit is being done and the result is being processed. Can I have some insights on this.

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0'; 
if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
  echo "<script>window.location.href='dashboard.php'</script>";die;
}
```

the above sent code is not of use.

Comment: You cannot stop fundamental functions of a browser like refresh or stopping page load. What you need to do is devise a system that works *despite* of anything the user may do client side. Which mostly means a lot of state keeping and validation **on the server**.

Comment: I sure hope that is never possible. I fear ads will be popups that can't be closed

Comment: You can't prevent user from closing the window but you can warn using the onbeforeunload event https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own

Comment: At most you can just add a `confirmation popup`  using `onbeforeunload` but you can't restrict user to close browser window.

Comment: Its not about closing the window. Whenever a request is made on browser to a page the browser loads the page and during that time the stop loading the page is clicked.

Comment: So, how would you conceptually think it possible to send something to the browser with your page that would prevent the browser from cancelling your page to load? Like… what if I cancel right in the middle of that *something* being loaded…? No, you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Why a down-vote? Can someone explain

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Ajax to preventing the user from stop your request.

If the time exceds 30 minutes, send a request to your server "underground" submitting the user's form.

You can use JQuery Ajax or any other that you like.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        confirm( "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?" );
    }
</script>
```

You can use onbeforeunload

Comment: which page i should put this code on. Actually my page for displaying Quiz and processing quiz are different. `quiz.php` and `processquiz.php` are two pages.

Comment: display page. Thats the one you want to protect, right?

Comment: See , the display page auto submits on time lapse. So when posting the values from quiz.php to processquiz.php the user is interrupting.

Comment: You need that code on the page that you want to protect. both of them if nessessary

Answer (score -2):

Just a suggestion - why don't you use an alert on that time-out, to inform the user what you are doing and that can they please wait? then at least they have to close that window before continuing.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert(" Your quiz is currently being auto-saved, please do not close your window."); }, 18000000);
```

Just cater the timeout to fit your own.